# How do I detect a mouseover on custom <li> bullet?

Tags: html, javascript

I have a list with custom image bullets. If the user hovers her mouse over the bullet image, I'd like to either:

- display a title attribute, or
- display helper text

I can use JavaScript-based solutions, if needed

My source looks like this:

```
<style>
  li.important { list-style-image: url(important.png) }
</style>
<ul>
  <li class="important">Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**: I want the mouseover/title text to appear only over the bullet, but *not* over the body of the `<li>`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible to pickup a mouseover of the **bullet** rather than just the `<li>` item.

One alternative (which is a bit dirty, but hey) is to include your "bullet" as part of your markup.

```
<li><img src="important.gif" alt="Something" title="Hey! Useful info!" /> Test</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('li.important').mouseover();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm failing to see the problem with the first bullet point you mentioned:

http://jsfiddle.net/xrGqk/2/

Tested setting a title attribute on a custom image `LI` in Chrome, FF, IE7. Mouse over the image on the `LI` and the title pops up in all three browsers.

`onmouseover` seems to work fine as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/xrGqk/4/

You should have an alert when you mouse over the `LI` custom image bullet.

Give these a try and see if they work for you. If so, consider posting the code that is giving you problems.

Comment: In case you want to have different pop up text for the `LI` and its image http://jsfiddle.net/xrGqk/3/ as far as I've seen you can't have only the bullet with title text